# Failing to install package.json. It only installs with a blank name and a blank version

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am failing to install package.json after installing the latest version of node on my PC(windows). When I initiated the npm it threw an error.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated

cmd prompt

**C:\Users\Felix\Desktop\Everything\Self Equipment\OOP Javascript>npm init

This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.

It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.

npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME

npm ERR! Invalid tag name "OOP Javascript": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

About to write to C:\Users\Felix\Desktop\Everything\Self Equipment\OOP Javascript\package.json:

{
  "name": "",
  "version": ""
}

Is this ok? (yes) n

Aborted.**

Also

[image: screen shot of error]

Comment: Don't post pictures of text! Post text!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the error message. (Which I can't copy/paste from your picture).

Now look what happens when you encode your package name using the method described in the error message.

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent("OOO JavaScript"));
```

The space is converted to `%20`.

You can't have a space in a package name. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, using `npm init` on npmv5.4.2, it does not allow capital letters. use lowercase letters and special characters like underscore(_). I'm sure this has to do with resolution of a package name by the package manager which has to be url-friendly.